# Tracking if phrase exists within a list of terms

Tags: arrays, excel, excel-formula

I am having difficulty finding a formula to do exactly what I am looking for.

I have two lists, one containing search phrases like ("Sound bars for tv") and another list that contains individual terms like ("TV", "Sound", "bars").

My goal is to see if any of the search phrases match for each keyword within the individual term list.

So for "Sound bars for TV", I would need each of those words to be in the term list for it to come back as a TRUE. Also, and more complicated, if I have the search phrase "Soundbar" and "Sound Bar" these should both pass if both terms are in the list.

Any idea what is the best way to approach this.

I have tried the following unsuccessfully:

Individual terms = the list of terms like "TV", "Sound", "Bars"
Phrase = search phrases like "Sound bars for TV"

The goal would be to create a formula that says "Yes" every word in "Sound bars for TV" is within the Individual terms list.

1. `=SUMPRODUCT(--ISNUMBER(SEARCH(individual terms,phrase)))=COUNTA(individual terms)`
2. `=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(phrase,individual terms)), "Yes", "No")`
3. `=SUMPRODUCT(--ISNUMBER(SEARCH(individual terms,phrase)))>0`

Comment: not every word in in the list, you do not have `for` in the list.

Comment: @ScottCraner I think that's the problem, the OP expects the formula to return `FALSE`, but all of the shown attempted formulas would return `TRUE`.

Comment: @ScottCraner - correct, if "for" is not in the list then "Sound bars for TV" would be a fail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's pretend you have a data setup like this:

[image]

Column D was made into an Excel table (with Insert -> Table) and named `tblTerms`.  This lets you add and remove terms from the list dynamically.

Now in cell B2 and copied down is this formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(COUNTIF(tblTerms[Search Terms],TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A2," ",REPT(" ",LEN(A2))),LEN(A2)*(ROW(A$1:INDEX(A:A,LEN(A2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A2," ",""))+1))-1)+1,LEN(A2))))=0))=0
```

Note that you'll have to add "Soundbars" separately to the search terms list.  There's not really any way for Excel to recognize individual words in a compound word, and attempting to do that would be extremely unwieldy, even with VBA.

Comment: Question, I have Memory Card as both a phrase and a term and it is not coming up as a match. Is this because of the spacing? How can I adjust for that?

Comment: Yes, it's because of the space. If your terms are going to have spaces, them VBA is the only real solution. If possible, use underscores instead of spaces in your search terms. Or just put memory and card separately.

Answer (score 2):

This will parse the string and count the matches then compare that to the number of "words" in the string.  If they match then it will return `Yes`

```
=IF(SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIF(D:D,TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",REPT(" ",999)),(ROW($XFD$1:INDEX($XFD:$XFD,LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",""))+1))-1)*999+1,999))))=LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",""))+1,"Yes","No")
```

[image]